# Animate marginLeft to element's -width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have element with long inline text and want to make animation that will move this text from off-screen right (whole text behind right border of window) to the left off-screen.

My idea is to move element by setting margin-left to minus(width) of element:

```js
var element = $(this);
$("p").animate({
  'marginLeft': - element;
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>element with long long long long inline text....</p>
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, as far as I can tell, `$(this)` is the window.  You want to animate the `$("p")` itself, and you need to specify you're animating based on it's width, not the general DOM element.  There also was a rogue `;` in your object that you were sending to the `animate` function (you can see errors like this in your Developer Tools Console).

```js
var $element = $("p");

$element.animate({
  'marginLeft': -($element.outerWidth())
}, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* no horizontal scrollbar */
}
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>element with long long long long inline text....</p>
```

**EDIT**

Or, here it is with pure CSS.  This is the more effective route to take, if the browsers you're developing for support it.  It causes the browser to "repaint" less, and runs on the GPU instead of CPU like JS does.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* no horizontal scrollbar */
}

@-webkit-keyframes offscreenLeft {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes offscreenLeft {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-o-keyframes offscreenLeft {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes offscreenLeft {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%; /* translate uses the inner width of the p tag, so the thing pushing it offscreen needs to be *inside* the p, not outside (like margin is) */
  
  -webkit-animation: offscreenLeft 4s forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    offscreenLeft 4s forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      offscreenLeft 4s forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         offscreenLeft 4s forwards; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<p>element with long long long long inline text....</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had problem with absolute position with p tag, so i removed it, and now I am using your solution. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: `position:absolute;` may also work; it really depends on how the rest of the content on your page is interacting with this.  You could also, depending on the browsers you need to support, use pure CSS, like in @azium's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would toggle a class on the element and using CSS's `transform: translateX()` combined with `transition` to move the element off screen.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/rOLPEB)

css

```
p {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

p.off-screen-right {
  transform: translateX(100%)
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function () {
    $('p').toggleClass('off-screen-right')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Steps

- Get the `<p>` width and save it in a variable.
- Then, sets the initial `margin-left` to the `$(window).width()`
- After that, you can call the `animate` function to set the `margin-left` to the negative value of the width you've saved in the variable initially

#### Working code

```js
$(function() {
  var width = $("p").width();
  
  $("p")
    .css('margin-left', $(window).width())
    .animate({ 'margin-left': -width }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>element with long long long long inline text....</p>
```